# Outlook mail folder showing nothing

Tags: vba, outlook

I am searching for Outlook mail.

```vb
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant   
Dim myTasks As Outlook.Items 
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
Set myTasks = Fldr.Items 
Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""8094676688""")
```

In myTasks and olMail I am geting nothing.

Comment: Appears the error due to missing `olNs` is bypassed.  `myTasks` and `olMail`  can only be nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Think, this case is better to do via loop

```
Dim count as Long
count=0
For Each x in myTasks 
If x.Subject ="8094676688" Then 
count=count+1
ReDim Preserve  olMail (count)
olMail (count)=x
End If
next x
```